# when i tried @google-cloud/translate.v2 api package in node js iam always getting user rate limit exceeded

Tags: node.js

`const translate = new Translate({projectId,key});
body={
"text":"How are you",
"sourceLangauage":"English",
"targetLanguage":"Kannada"
}

app.post('/text', async (req, res) => {

```
const { text,sourceLangauage, targetLanguage } = req.body;
const originLanguage=getLanguageKey(sourceLangauage)
const destinationLanguage=getLanguageKey(targetLanguage);
console.log("................................",destinationLanguage)



try {
  const  [translation] = await translate.translate(text, {from:originLanguage,to:destinationLanguage});
  console.log("text")
  console.log(translation,".................................................")
  res.json({ translation}); // Output the translated text
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Translation error:', error);
  res.status(500).json({ error: 'Translation error' });
}
```

});

`

`just i want language translation of particular text`